# Oracle Regex Patterns

Tags: regex, oracle

I have 3 Regex patterns from oracle 10/11 that I need to port to oracle 9. However, I am getting different results when I try to do the matching. Is there a way to fix this ? Is it even possible to port these patterns and get the same results when matching ?

Here are the patterns:

```
'^[[:alnum:]\_]$' which I would think would map to '[A-Za-z0-9_]*$'

'^[[:alpha:]]$' which i would think would map to '^[A-Za-z]*$'

'^(\"|\'')' which I would think needs to map over into 2 patterns '^["]*$' or '^['']*$'
```

[owa pattern docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a90101/pspatt.htm)

[oracle 10g regex docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm#i690819)

EDIT:
So my question was originally part of a lexor that was giving me trouble in a parser..it turns out my problem was related to a type (and not the regex) ..My regex patterns match close enough(and actually I changed the  :alnum to use "\w" instead of the other pattern.)

There's one thing I still don't understand what does double enclosing brackets mean [[  with in the example regex ?

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be most helpful.  With sample data, show what row(s) your regular expressions match (and don't match) and what row(s) your `owa_pattern` code matches (or doesn't match).

Comment: The problem is the regex patterns are a part of a JSON Pl/SQL Parser (https://sourceforge.net/projects/pljson/files/PL_JSON/v1.0.4/) that I'm trying to add 9i support for. I'm able to adjust the regex to get some of the patterns but not all of the right ones.. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=36.151182431248,-86.7864990234375&sensor=false is the data I am parsing..